# How to manage shorter transaction inside Spring Batch chunk?

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-batch

I've got a problem using Spring Batch and can't seem to find a solution.

So, I've got a batch processing some items in chunks (size 10). I've also got a transaction manager used by this batch to persist the processed items after each chunk.

But... I would also like to persist some progress status for those items, in real time. So before processing an item I want to save a status saying this item is in progress.

And I can't seem to find a solution to achieve that. I tried the following solutions :

1. If I just annotate my status manager service with **Transactional** annotation the statuses are commited after the whole chunk processing.
2. If I add **REQUIRES_NEW** as propagation level to the annotation, it works... but the batch ends in some kind of deadlock (I read that it was common issue with **REQUIRES_NEW**).
3. So my last guess was to add a second transaction manager (on the same datasource) and use it on the status manager service... But I got the same result as solution #1 (which seem wierd to me as I expected the transaction from this manager to act independently of the chunk transaction).

Has anybody ever encountered this problem?

EDIT :
Here is my configuration, simplified on purpose :

Class DbConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
public class DbConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @Primary
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() throws Exception {
        final JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
        jpaTransactionManager.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jpaTransactionManager;
    }
}
```

Class JobConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
@Import(DbConfiguration.class)
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JobConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    @Bean
    public Job jobDefinition() {
        return jobBuilderFactory
            .get(JOB_NAME)
            .start(step())
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step step() {
        return stepBuilderFactory
            .get(STEP_NAME)
            .<Object, Object>chunk(COMMIT_INTERVAL)
                    .reader(reader())
                    .processor(processor())
                    .writer(writer())
            .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager statusTransactionManager() {
        final JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        jpaTransactionManager.afterPropertiesSet();
        return jpaTransactionManager;
    }
}
```

Class StatusManagerServiceImpl:

```
@Transactional("statusTransactionManager")
public class StatusManagerServiceImpl implements StatusManagerService {
    ...
}
```

Comment: I wouldn't expect 1 or 2 to work for reasons you can find elsewhere in StackOverflow.  Can you provide your configuration for 3?

Comment: Hi Michael!

I just added my configuration, simplified to focus on the problem.

I hope it will suffice.

Comment: Who is causing the `StatusManagerService`?

Comment: This service is called in multiple situations:
- When process begins
- When a reader, processor or writer fails
- At the end of the step

Comment: All from listeners?

Comment: Yes but I don't declare them explicitly, I use the corresponding annotations instead.

Comment: No more idea :-) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A way to achieve this is to use Spring TransactionTemplate as follows:

```
@Service
public class StatusManagerServiceImpl implements StatusManagerService {
    @Autowired
    private PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager;

    public separateTransactionMethod() {
        TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(transactionManager);
        transactionTemplate.execute(new TransactionCallbackWithoutResult() {
            @Override
            protected void doInTransactionWithoutResult(TransactionStatus status) {
                // Do something here that will be committed right away.
            }
        });
    }
}
```

You can alternatively use new TransactionCallback if you got a result to return. Then execute method would return that result.